# JSDOC on socket.io emit

Tags: javascript, socket.io, jsdoc

If I have socketio function like this :

```
_sock.emit('app_version',appversion,(response)=>{
   console.log(response)
})
```

and I want to put a proper JSDOC , explaining that appversion is a string, and response is a string, how do i write it ?

currently tried some combination like @param , or @property in WebStorm, yet Webstorm still don't recognize that appversion and response type.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

JSDoc works best if you type things as you declare them, which doesn't work very well if you're doing things inline (such as using an inline arrow function. Try something like this, declaring and typing your variables and functions *before* using them:

```
// Use @type to indicate the type of the next following variable
/**
 * @type {string}
 */
let appversion;

// Use @param to indicate the param type of the next following function
/**
 * @param {string} response
 */
function doThing(response) {
  console.log(response);
}

_sock.emit('app_version', appversion, doThing);
```